# PHP: Passing Objects with methods between pages

Tags: php

There are varied existing questions regarding passing PHP class objects between pages, mostly by serializing, compressing, etc. However, the methods of the object don't get passed.

I have a class say:

```
class Car
 {
   public function BrakeStatus()
   {
     //Fetch some sql data and return status of brakes
   }
 }
```

In page "page1.php"

```
<?php
$car = new Car;
$link = "<a href='page2.php?car=".$car."'>Click here</a>";
echo $link;
?>
```

In page "page2.php"

```
<?php
$car2=$_REQUEST('car');
$car2_brakes=$car2->BrakeStatus();
?>
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You cannot pass object like that, you only able to pass strings via links. You need to decide: pass every values of your object (do not forget that user could change any value) or pass id of object end retrieve object by id.

Comment: Object methods are not serialized and you are not un-serializing the $_REQUEST['car'] value

Comment: I understand, and the code is only an indicator example. The question is, how can I pass Object methods?

Comment: Use your session to store your serialized objects there. $_SESSION['car'] = serialize($car); And on page2.php $car = unserialze($_SESSION['car']);

Comment: Your methods will be available once you unserialize.

Comment: @Andreas: If what you say is true i.e. "the methods will be available", I'm thrilled to try this. I'll revert later today and post my findings. Thanks, to all!

Answer (score 0):

So, I see only one way do this:
Car.php:

```
<?php
class Car
{
    public function BrakeStatus()
    {
        echo 'Test string!';
    }
}
```

page1.php:

```
<?php
$carFilePath = 'Car.php';
require($carFilePath);
$car = new Car;

$carString = serialize($car);
$carImplementation = str_replace('<?php', '', file_get_contents('Car.php'));
$data = [
    'carString' => $carString,
    'carImplementation' => $carImplementation,
];
$JSONData = json_encode($data);
$link = "<a href='page2.php?car=".$JSONData."'>Click here</a>";
echo $link;
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
$carJSON=$_REQUEST('car');
$data = json_decode($carJSON);
eval($data->carImplementation);
$car = unserialize($data->carString);
$car->BrakeStatus();
```

But if you need this, you have architecture problems. Please read "Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications" by Grady Booch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grady_Booch). This is contrary to the concept of object-oriented programming (hiding implementation).

**So as if you are really thinking is suddenly applied, please encrypt $ JSONData asynchronous key!!!**